# r replace doesn't work with Hungarian letters

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset where I need to rename some words from Hungarian language to English.

I have noticed that for words with some Hungarian letters which do not exist in English language *replace* doesn't work.

For example, in

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(attic_type = replace(
    attic_type, attic_type == "nem tetőtéri", "not_attic")) %>%
  mutate(attic_type = replace(
    attic_type, attic_type == "nincs megadva", "not_specified")) %>%
  mutate(attic_type = replace(
    attic_type, attic_type == "legfelső emelet (nem tetőtéri)", "top_floor")) %>%
  mutate(attic_type = replace(
    attic_type, attic_type == "tetőtéri", "rooftop")) %>%
  mutate(attic_type = replace(
    attic_type, attic_type == "zárószint", "final_level"))
```

`nem tetőtéri`, `legfelső emelet (nem tetőtéri)`, `tetőtéri` were not translated

```
A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   attic_type [6]
  attic_type                         n
  <chr>                          <int>
1 nem tetőtéri                   32962
2 not_specified                  30601
3 legfelső emelet (nem tetőtéri)  2036
4 tetőtéri                        1251
5 penthouse                        157
6 final_level                      109
```

Does anyone have any ideas what to do in such cases?

Comment: could you add a `dput` of data?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your script in "UTF-8" and also do:

```
Encoding(data) <- "UTF-8"
```

Comment: script was initially saved as UTF-8

Comment: Did you literally mean I need to enter Encoding(data) <- "UTF-8"? It returns this error: ```Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "UTF-8") : 
  a character vector argument expected```

Comment: My bad, I meant Encoding(data$attic_type) <- "UTF-8"

Comment: Hi, no, Encoding(data$attic_type) <- "UTF-8" did not help